# how to make full screen iframe google maps in wordpress widget Raw HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm working on the contact page WordPress I am using Google Maps iframe embed so at WPBakery builder plugin I found Raw HTML widget which I set all iframe Google Maps.

[image]

```css
.map-responsive {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
}

.map-responsive iframe {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 550px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="map-responsive">
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2996.145230917005!2d19.806475715791027!3d41.32745520767062!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x135031c2c95695d5%3A0x81dc10c851ceadac!2sSan%20Luca%20Klinik%C3%AB%20Mjek%C3%ABsore!5e0!3m2!1ssq!2s!4v1667130638394!5m2!1ssq!2s"
    width="100%" height="550" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
</div>
```

After  that, my results of the iframe Google Maps is as below:
[image]

But my purpose of the using  Google Maps iframe embed is to make full screen in the left and right which now is empty, any idea how to make it??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add `allowfullscreen` at end of the tag

Try this snippet

```html
<div class="map-responsive">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2996.145230917005!2d19.806475715791027!3d41.32745520767062!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x135031c2c95695d5%3A0x81dc10c851ceadac!2sSan%20Luca%20Klinik%C3%AB%20Mjek%C3%ABsore!5e0!3m2!1ssq!2s!4v1667130638394!5m2!1ssq!2s" width="100%" height="550" style="border:0;" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer now iframe Google Maps is full screen, but it is only in HTML we want to be on WordPress raw HTML widget. thanks